# ELMAH YSOD in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah, debug-mode, ysod

I've recently implemented ELMAH in one of our production apps. It's really been a rather easy implementation and it's working flawlessly. However, I'm noticing the YSOD in prod isn't as telling as it is in dev. The main reason being that in prod we have Debug="false" and in dev it's true. We have a custom error page that an end user would see. What I would like to know is:

a. Do you also get the trimmed down YSOD because you don't run your app in debug mode?

b. Are you running prod with debug = true to see the "dev" YSOD?

c. Is there a configuration setting that will give me the best of both worlds?

EDIT: from the lack of responses, either I'm not asking the right questions (my MO on SO) or no one out there deals with this quasi issue. Not even a bounty can draw some responses?

Answer (score 0):

You're right you are getting a cut down version as you are running with the debug flag set false. You have 2 options really;

1. Run the app in debug mode (albeit temporarily whilst you fix issues
2. Add `Debug="true"` to the Page directive at the top of the erroring page which *should* give you the full output for that page.

There is no halfway house unfortunately. FYI I run sites with debug=false enabling debug=true only when we have to debug errors.